# How to remove prefixes from strings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some text preprocessing so that I can do some string matching activities.

I have a set of strings,  i want to check if the first word in the string starts with "1/" prefix. If it does, I want to remove this prefix but maintain the rest of the word/string.

I've come up with the following, but its just removing everything after the first word and not necessarily removing the prefix "1/"

```
prefixes = (r'1/')
#remove prefixes from string
def prefix_removal(text):
    for word in str(text).split():
        if word.startswith(prefixes):
            return word[len(prefixes):]
        else:
            return word
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Try `s.split(prefix)[-1]` it should work even when prefix not exist, but if the prefix appeared several times in your string so it would take the string after last occurance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want to remove the prefix from the first word and leave the rest alone, I see no reason to use a for loop. Instead, I would recommend this:

```
def prefix_removal(text):
    first_word = text.split()[0]
    if first_word.startswith(prefixes):
         return text[len(prefixes):]
    return text
```

Hopefully this answers your question, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Python 3.9 you can use [`str.removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix):

```
word = word.removeprefix(prefix)
```

For other versions of Python you can use:

```
if word.startswith(prefix):
    word = word[len(prefix):]
```

Comment: currently cannot use python 3.9

Comment: @mikelowry For other versions of Python you can use the equivalent version given in the docs. I've updated my answer.